# Error Message: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero at survey.results(survey.java:51)

Tags: java, bluej

I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong here; s you can see by the "//" parts, I've tried different ways:

```
public class survey {
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private double total = 12467;
    // private double percentage = 100;
    private double one = total * .14; // percentage;
    private double citrus = total * .64; // percentage;

    public void results(int total) {

        System.out.println("Number of people surveyed:" + total);
        System.out.println("Number who purchase one or more energy drinks:"
                + one);
        System.out.println("Number who prefer citrus flavored energy drinks:"
                + citrus);
    }
}
```

---

This is what I ended up doing, solved the error. Thanks for the prompt responses everyone!

```
/**
 * Write a description of class survey here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */ 

public class survey
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private double total = 12467;
    private double one = 14 ;
    private double citrus = 64 ;
    private int oneperc;
    private int citrusperc;
    {
    oneperc = (int) ((total*one/100));
}
   {
    citrusperc = (int) ((total*citrus/100));
}

public void results(int total)
{
    System.out.println("Number of people surveyed:" + total);
        System.out.println("Number who purchase one or more energy drinks:" + oneperc);
            System.out.println("Number who prefer citrus flavored energy drinks:" + citrusperc);
        }
}
```

Comment: Fixed your tags, Java != Javascript

Comment: Which statement is line 51?  Why is the parameter an `int`?

Comment: I don't see where you're dividing anything.

Comment: You can press [[edit]] under your question to add more info and clarify where is line 51. Right now we can only say that you divided some value by zero in line 51, but without actual code that we can use to reproduce your error we cant answer "why/how".

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the `public void results(double total)` to accept a double, and it run successfully.

Are you sure this is all of your code?

Comment: Yes, that was all. Sorry, clumsy replying here... Bad newbie